# Is "he takes extreme measures to ensure that he is seen by no one" a complex sentence?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, complex-sentences, compound-sentences

"he takes extreme measures to ensure that he is seen by no one"

I am confused. Is it a complex sentence? If so which is the Independent clause and which is the Dependent clause?

I know that " he takes extreme measures" is an independent clause and "that he is seen by no one" is a dependent clause.

But what is " to ensure" in this context?

Comment: ELL at ell.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

- *He takes extreme measures to ensure that he is seen by no one*

Let's [take it apart](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/Howtofigureoutasentence.pdf), shall we?

First, insert the missing clause marker *in order* for the purpose infinitive, and identify auxiliary verbs (in this case, only *is*).

- *He takes extreme measures **in order** to ensure that he **is** seen by no one*

Next, identify and count the remaining main verbs. This is the number of clauses.

- *He **takes** extreme measures to **ensure** that he is **seen** by no one*
  Present tense *takes*, infinitive *ensure*, present passive *seen*. Three verbs, three clauses.

Next, identify the type of each clause.

- *[He takes extreme measures [in order to ensure [that he is seen by no one]]]*
- *He takes extreme measures* [*in order to* `S`] : main clause, present tense, subject *He*
- [*in order to*] *ensure* [*that* `S`] : purpose infinitive sentence adverb clause, no subject
- [*that*] *he is seen by no one* : passive present tensed direct object complement of *ensure*

Finally, identify missing subjects -- *he* is the subject of *ensure* in the purpose infinitive, under identity with the subject of *takes* -- and unwind rules, in this case only Passive in the complement clause, which produces

- *[He takes extreme measures [in order for him to ensure [that no one sees him]]]*

So, since it has one main clause and two dependent clauses, I guess this is a complex sentence. Though that's not important; most sentences are complex; simple sentences only occur in grade school and on TV news.

Comment: Or in quarrels! :-) _Stop it!_ +1, taught me something, there is less fog in my English grammar.